# where does myeclipse console output come from?

Tags: java, debugging, myeclipse, console-output

recently I try to review an old JavaWeb project written in Myeclipse, it is sort of bulky. I start Tomcat and console output shows:

> 1
>
> 1
>
> filter--in

I remember that I added a filter, so the `filter--in` is ok, I know where it comes from and where to find source code that generates this output.

But,the double wired `1` above is not. I hava no idea which code line made this output. I must have written some code like `System.out.println("1")` in order to debug when I built this project long time ago.

I try to find an easy way to find the output generator code. Here are ways I think that might work:

- dig deeply line by line until I find it ( it's stupid and it waste time )
- use debug mode of MyEclipse. ( I tried, but it seems that I still need to know where is the target code in order to set breakpoint)

I don't think that I master the way to solve it. Are there tips or skills that work or work easier?

Answer (score 0):

You could try one of the search facilities (Search Text, Search Java) or you could put a breakpoint in the java.io.PrintStream.println(String) method (and/or similar methods) and trace the stack back to your code when the breakpoint is hit during a debugging session.